# CentOS Linux release 8.0.1905 not taking change of php.ini

Tags: php, server-sent-events, output-buffering, centos8

I want to remove **output_buffering** and want to make change to **memory_limit** by editing etc/php.ini file

But none of my changes are taking effect. 
After editing etc/php.ini file as a super user. I've restarted httpd.service using following command

```
sudo systemctl restart httpd.service
```

I am using centOS 8

```
[root@backend adminuser]# cat /etc/*release
CentOS Linux release 8.0.1905 (Core)
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="8 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="8"
PLATFORM_ID="platform:el8"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 8 (Core)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:8"
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-8"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="8"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="8"

CentOS Linux release 8.0.1905 (Core)
CentOS Linux release 8.0.1905 (Core)
```

php-common packages are as below

```
[root@backend adminuser]# rpm -qc php-common
/etc/php-zts.d/20-bz2.ini
/etc/php-zts.d/20-calendar.ini
/etc/php-zts.d/20-ctype.ini
/etc/php-zts.d/20-curl.ini
/etc/php-zts.d/20-exif.ini
/etc/php-zts.d/20-fileinfo.ini
/etc/php-zts.d/20-ftp.ini
/etc/php-zts.d/20-gettext.ini
/etc/php-zts.d/20-iconv.ini
/etc/php-zts.d/20-phar.ini
/etc/php-zts.d/20-sockets.ini
/etc/php-zts.d/20-tokenizer.ini
/etc/php.d/20-bz2.ini
/etc/php.d/20-calendar.ini
/etc/php.d/20-ctype.ini
/etc/php.d/20-curl.ini
/etc/php.d/20-exif.ini
/etc/php.d/20-fileinfo.ini
/etc/php.d/20-ftp.ini
/etc/php.d/20-gettext.ini
/etc/php.d/20-iconv.ini
/etc/php.d/20-phar.ini
/etc/php.d/20-sockets.ini
/etc/php.d/20-tokenizer.ini
/etc/php.ini
```

For SSE Script I want to make output_buffer as null or Off like my another server but its not taking any change. I tested by changing php.ini as a root user and restarted httpd services.

[image]

Comment: try this link this might help https://serverfault.com/questions/466622/php-ini-changes-dont-have-any-effect

Comment: Thanks Guarav. But that link mainly gives reference on how to display php configuration using phpinfo() function. That i already know and showed you sample in above image.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I am assuming you are using **php-fpm**
Following command worked for me.

1. Connect via terminal and **Make sure you are Super(Root) user**

   **sudo su**
2. Now run following command

   **sudo systemctl restart php-fpm.service**

**Note** : Test by making small change like increasing or decreasing **memory_limit** in php config file and run above command and review change using phpinfo()

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention whether you're using `mod_php` or `php-fpm`. Running `sudo systemctl restart httpd.service` only helps for `mod_php`. If you're using `php-fpm`, you need `sudo systemctl restart php-fpm.service` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Changing etc/php.ini  does not work any more.
You need to add your own .ini file now under "/etc/php.d" and restart php

confirm the path from phpinfo. Look for
"Scan this dir for additional .ini files    /etc/php.d"

create file (30 prefix to file name is like priority or how late to load):

```
sudo vi /etc/php.d/30-user.ini
```

Add entries like:

```
max_execution_time=200
post_max_size=100M
upload_max_filesize=100M
```

Restart PHP (restarting Apache does not help)

Check the service (if not present ..restarting Apache should work: sudo systemctl restart httpd )

```
sudo systemctl status php-fpm
```

Resart the service

```
sudo systemctl restart php-fpm
```